# Can you automatically test if external dependencies (e.g. a website) behave as expected?

Tags: unit-testing, dependencies

I'm in a situation where a part of my application depends on a website which I have no control over. The website might change unexpectedly and without warning, and the changes may or may not break a part in my application. When that happens, I always have to figure out what changed and how I need to change my application to understand the change.

Now I thought, wouldn't it make sense to somehow test this website for changes, similar to how unit tests indicate behavior contrary to the specification? I could see immediately what changed and would probably notice it sooner than waiting for my app to fail.

Comment: "Unit" test, by definition, means a completely isolated piece of code, that allows you to define all inputs and outputs. You probably mean "automated" testing, of which unit testing is subset.

Comment: @Euphoric Okay, got me on that one. Although it is incorrect, I like to call all kinds of automated tests unit tests...

Comment: Then, I wouldn't be surprised if answers you get will not help you or even misinform you.

Comment: @Euphoric Better now?

Comment: @Namnodorel: I suggest you change the title to something like "Can you automatically test a dependency on a web site", because that is what you are asking. Testing "external dependencies" is a very broad term, if someone reads that literally, he will probably vote for closing your question as "too broad".

Comment: Have you looked into something like [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software))?

Comment: can you define what "as expected" mean? Color of output? id-s of certain input/output-controls? password to access the side? order of result colums? wich url is called if you press the ok button? more background would be helpful.

Comment: @Robbie Dee I know Selenium, but it is an API and not a testing framework, so it isn't really suitable

Comment: @k3b "As expected" means most of the time that it returns information in a specific format or for example when I send the argument increase=true&valname=commentcounter I expect the server to display the value commentcounter higher every time I request a page.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Although I have forgotten the name of it, writing a suite of tests to understand how a 3rd party component behaves and to ensure that this behavior does not change is hardly unusual.

Of course, since you are testing against a black box, there may be a number of issues, such as

- causing side effects that you don't want,
- in the case of websites, putting load on the server
- in some cases, usage of a service may cost money.

Answer (score 0):

Original question was: **Can you unit test external dependencies?**
Original Answer: No, testing external dependencies is called integration testing

After reading your comments, i believe that what you are looking for is called "contract testing"! check it out, they are meant to ensure that the reply is in the correct form, and that the "contract" has not changed/broken...

I said that you "can't" unit test an external dependency because if you say that whole system that is being exposed as a endpoint is a UNIT, than whatever else you have under regular unit tests is smaller than a unit! can you see the discrepancy in the definition?!?

But, can you do it? yes you can. Should you treat an external dependency as a unit? no you shouldn't...

Comment: As far as I know, integration testing are tests where I test how my code interacts with a dependency. But I'd leave my application code entirely aside for these tests, only testing if the website behaves as expected...

Comment: @Namnodorel in that case, can you further explain what you expect to unit test on the external dependency? imagine that your external dependency is a email service via a DLL, so you plan to test the `myDLL.Send(mail, me@me.com)` and look at you inbox?

Comment: Kinda. In my specific case I make a call with specific arguments to the server and expect to get the result in a certain format. Like, I expect it to return "[number]/[number]" so "163/54 (+two cats)" would fail.

Comment: @Namnodorel check out the edit